# SQL userID auto increment

Tags: mysql, sql, database, unique, userid

Mysql database is like that;

```
userID -> primaryKey, required, unsigned integer, auto increment, unique
usermail -> unique,varchar,required
```

I'm creating new users. userId is auto increment. If usermail inserted before,it occurs an error. My question is this

```
Let's think that userID is between 1-9.(there are 9 users now). 
Somebody has inserted same usermail before and took error. 
After that,new user inserted another usermail but userID became 11 instead 10. 
Why? What should i do to make it 10?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it necessary for you to increment the userID from Database properties itself. Because what I am saying is, before inserting any records, just retrieve the last userID from database, store it in a integer variable and then increment it and insert back into database along with the new record.

Say your last user id was 9.
Use this query - `Select max(userID) from "your table";`

```
int x=0;
SqlDataReader dr=com.ExecuteReader();
if(dr.HasRows)
{
    While(dr.Read())
    {
       x=Convert.ToInt32(dr.GetString(0).ToString);
    }
}
x=x+1;
```

Now since you have new `x` value, easily insert it back to database with new record.
So that auto increment will be followed and even though failure occurs insertion will not be done and `UserID` does not increase.

Comment: Yes this solution is what i was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When the error is being caused it seems to be inserting a new row and incrementing the uniqueid. On error you will need to query the table for the latest ID and reset the auto increment value

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` AUTO_INCREMENT =new_number_here
```

Found Here: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,16088,17748#msg-17748

Comment: Is it possible to add a parameter inside my.ini file? Is it a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to merge the insert clause with the select check like below .

it is a behavior of mysql that it increments the counter also for the error and for the successful insertion

```
INSERT INTO [table name] SELECT '[value1]', '[value2]' FROM DUAL
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
SELECT [column1] FROM [same table name]
WHERE [column1]='[value1]'
AND [column2]='[value2]' LIMIT 1    )
```

Here you can see the how you can prevent the `insert` clause [insert-where-not-exists](http://www.timrosenblatt.com/blog/2008/03/21/insert-where-not-exists/) using this technique the counter will increase when data is inserted and duplicate data will be ignored

Comment: is there a way like adding a parameter inside my.ini file to solve this problem?

Comment: No there is no way to stop the `counter` of `auto_increment` by query or by `my.ini` here is the detail of developers of mysql http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html about the `AUTO_INCREMENT Handling in InnoDB`